# How to use gdb.pretty_pointers to print struct's pointer member?

Tags: python, c, debugging, gdb

I have a C struct like this:

```
typedef uint8_t matrix_size_t;
typedef float ElemType;
struct _matrix {
  /* data */
  uint8_t inited;
  matrix_size_t rows;
  matrix_size_t cols;
  ElemType* data;
};
```

I want to print Matrix.data with row and col format, here is my python code:

```
import gdb
import numpy as np
import logging


class McuMatrixPrinter:

    def __init__(self, variety, val):
        self.variety = variety
        self.inited = val["inited"]
        self.rows = int(val["rows"])
        self.cols = int(val["cols"])
        self.data = val["data"]
        self.type = self.data.type.unqualified().strip_typedefs()
        self.data = self.data.cast(self.type.pointer())
        logging.info(self.type)
        logging.info(type(self.data))

    def to_string(self):
        if int(self.inited) == 0:
            return "This matrix has not been inited!"
        mat = np.zeros((self.rows, self.cols), dtype=np.float64)
        for row in range(self.rows):
            for col in range(self.cols):
                offset = row * self.cols + col
                item = (self.data + offset).dereference()
                logging.info(type(item))
                mat[row, col] = float(item)
        return "Matrix::%s<%d,%d>\n%s\n" % (self.variety, self.rows, self.cols,
                                            self.data, mat)


def PrintMatrix(val):
    type = val.type
    if type.code == gdb.TYPE_CODE_REF:
        type = type.target()

    type = type.unqualified().strip_typedefs()
    typename = type.tag
    if typename == None:
        return None
    if typename.find("_matrix") != -1:
        return McuMatrixPrinter("Matrix", val)
    return None


def register_matrix_printers(obj):
    "Register eigen pretty-printers with objfile Obj"
    logging.basicConfig(
        level=logging.DEBUG, 
        filename='/tmp/gdbpy.log',
        filemode='a',
        format=
        '%(asctime)s - %(pathname)s[line:%(lineno)d] - %(levelname)s: %(message)s'
    )
    if obj == None:
        obj = gdb
    obj.pretty_printers.append(PrintMatrix)
```

However, I got this exception:

(gdb) p vector
$1 = Python Exception <class 'gdb.error'> Cannot convert value to float.:

(gdb) p vector
$2 = Python Exception <class 'gdb.error'> Cannot convert value to float.:

Is there a soution can solve my problem?

Comment: What is ElemType? Do you have a complete example?

Comment: I'm very sorry, ElemType is float. This typedef is added to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line in the constructor is the problem:

```
self.data = self.data.cast(self.type.pointer())
```

`self.type` is `ElemType*` (pointer to `ElemType`) and we cast `self.data` to `ElemType**` (pointer to pointer to `ElemType`). But `to_string` offsets and dereferences `self.data` as you would a single pointer.

**Remove that line**

Answer (score 0):

I've found the cause of the type error,
        `return "Matrix::%s<%d,%d>\n%s\n" % (self.variety, self.rows, self.cols, self.data, mat)`
data cannot be converted to string, so is mat.

Now I use string and " += " to concat the result, and the matrix is printed successfully.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).